# What is the difference between IMMEDIATE_PAY and INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE in the PayPal REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Does anybody know what the difference is between the allowed payment methods `IMMEDIATE_PAY` and `INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE`?

The API documentation of PayPal is very confusing and the PayPal Java REST SDK I use also doesn't say anything about what these fields actually mean. Can somebody help me out?

What I basically want is to avoid the delayed payment option for the user so I am sure that the transaction is actually paid (money is transferred to my PayPal account). Need explanation on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMMEDIATE_PAY would be PayPal funds.  The funds are immediately available.

INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE would be a scenario like when the buyer doesn't have cash in the PayPal account, so he's using a bank account as the funding source, however, they do have a credit card attached to their PayPal account.  As such, PayPal sends the seller the money instantly, and then if the bank account payment (e-check) doesn't clear, then they would hit the credit card.

So in the case of instant funding there's still a chance the payment could fail.  For example, if the bank funds are not available and the credit card on file gets declined.

When you say "delayed payment" though, that sounds like you're referring to a "delayed chained payment" which would be a different thing, so I'm not entirely sure I'm answering your question here.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thnx! I guess I have to use the IMMEDIATE_PAY then because with that option the transaction will be paid immediately. The problem I was having is that a payment came through as paid but later on PayPal couldn't get the funds from the PayPal account or creditcard so I didn't receive the money but the customer did receive their product. Do you know if the PayPal API sends another type of status back when you try to execute the payment? In my scenario I got back the status "approved" which for me means it is paid. Or is that a wrong assumption?